# How to debug the Word Add-in (OfficeJS) with localhost API?

Tags: microsoft-word, security, office365, debug

We have one word add-in developed and we are facing this issue for long time. We wanted to debug the code by pointing the word add-in to local Web API. We are receiving the Access Denied error upon pointing this to local Web API. It works fine with hosted API.

We try to tunnel the local Web API using **ngrok** but it is still giving the same error. Looking for the workaround or solution for the same. Note that the issue is with both http and https localhost.